# Easier / more idiomatic way to do a "zip with conditional" in RXJS?

Tags: functional-programming, stream, rxjs

I'm trying to zip two Observables in RXJS, taking values from each in pairs when a certain condition is met. I found a way to accomplish this without using `zip`, but I was wondering if anybody knew of a more idiomatic way to do it.

```js
const { zip, merge, Subject } = require("rxjs");
const rxop = require("rxjs/operators");

const a$ = new Subject();
const b$ = new Subject();

// Zipping a$ and b$ on conditional a.n === b.n
const zippedWithCondition$ = merge(
  a$.pipe(
    rxop.mergeMap(aMsg => b$.pipe(
      rxop.find(bMsg => aMsg.n === bMsg.n),
      rxop.map(bMsg => [aMsg, bMsg])
    ))
  ),
  b$.pipe(
    rxop.mergeMap(bMsg => a$.pipe(
      rxop.find(aMsg => aMsg.n === bMsg.n),
      rxop.map(aMsg => [aMsg, bMsg])
    ))
  )
);
const withConditionSub = zippedWithCondition$.subscribe(msg => {
  console.log("[ZIPPED WITH CONDITION]", msg);
});
a$.next({n: 0, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 1, type: "b"});
a$.next({n: 1, type: "a"});
a$.next({n: 2, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 2, type: "b"});
b$.next({n: 0, type: "b"});
a$.next({n: 3, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 3, type: "b"});
withConditionSub.unsubscribe();

// Zipping a$ and b$ without a conditional
const normalZipped$ = zip(a$, b$);
const normalZippedSub = normalZipped$.subscribe(msg => {
  console.log("[NORMAL ZIP]", msg);
});
a$.next({n: 0, type: "a"}); // same order as above
b$.next({n: 1, type: "b"});
a$.next({n: 1, type: "a"});
a$.next({n: 2, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 2, type: "b"});
b$.next({n: 0, type: "b"});
a$.next({n: 3, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 3, type: "b"});
normalZippedSub.unsubscribe();
```

Output:

```js
[ZIPPED WITH CONDITION] [ { n: 1, type: 'a' }, { n: 1, type: 'b' } ]
[ZIPPED WITH CONDITION] [ { n: 2, type: 'a' }, { n: 2, type: 'b' } ]
[ZIPPED WITH CONDITION] [ { n: 0, type: 'a' }, { n: 0, type: 'b' } ]
[ZIPPED WITH CONDITION] [ { n: 3, type: 'a' }, { n: 3, type: 'b' } ]

[NORMAL ZIP] [ { n: 0, type: 'a' }, { n: 1, type: 'b' } ]
[NORMAL ZIP] [ { n: 1, type: 'a' }, { n: 2, type: 'b' } ]
[NORMAL ZIP] [ { n: 2, type: 'a' }, { n: 0, type: 'b' } ]
[NORMAL ZIP] [ { n: 3, type: 'a' }, { n: 3, type: 'b' } ]
```

See how for my `[ZIPPED WITH CONDITION]` the `n`'s match for each pair. For normal zip, that doesn't occur, because messages came in out-of-order.

So is there a better way to do this? Maybe in a way that is extensible to zipping any number of observables on a condition?

Comment: You should assume stream emit at random time without knowing what will come in and at what time, so to make zip in order is not realistic without setting a buffer period. If you doing is more like a predefined array processing, then it make sense to write some function to zip them in order.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution you are building ***2n + 2m*** observables. In other words, if `a$` emits **m** values and `b$` emits **n** values, you are creating ***2n + 2m*** observables.

To see this, you just need to add `complete` methods to `a$` and `b$` to your test data sequence, like in the following example

```
a$.next({n: 0, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 1, type: "b"});
a$.next({n: 1, type: "a"});
a$.next({n: 2, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 2, type: "b"});
b$.next({n: 0, type: "b"});
a$.next({n: 3, type: "a"});
b$.next({n: 3, type: "b"});
a$.complete();
b$.complete();
withConditionSub.unsubscribe();
```

I think that, in order to find a good solution, you should complete you requirements considering also the **time** variable. For instance: "`a$` and `b$` emit always objects with `n` property increased by 1 sequentially - no holes in the sequential sequence are foreseen - and so on and so for.

If time related requirements can not be specified, it is difficult to imagine an RxJS solution